# Can I make a HTTP callout from Oracle DB via java code

Tags: java, oracle, rest

Long ago I was consuming web service from Oracle DB with procedure that was generated with JPublisher. Simply providied URL of WS WSDL and JPublisher utility did the rest of procedure generation.

Now I need to make a call to REST service but with java code from Oracle DB. I googled for a while with no results. Is it possible or is it so trivial?

Comment: Is there a reason for wanting to do it from java code within the Oracle database rather than SQL / PL/SQL?

Comment: I would do it that way, but project leaders want it this way if we could have more control over it. However, I don't know (yet) how to do it via java. :)

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to make REST calls from java in the database. If PL/SQL was an option for you, then you can use HttpUriType() for simple HTTP GET calls, or APEX_WEB_SERVICE.MAKE_REST_REQUEST, or UTL_HTTP. I gave a presentation on these methods at ODTUG Kscope14 conference. You can read the presentation here: http://www.slideshare.net/KimBergHansen/oracle-36496025

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  You would store the HTTP command as an xml clob.  You would also need to have sys access in order to add the calling user to the network ACL.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not following you. Why storing HTTP command anywhere? Can you give me an example or some link to resources?